# Infinite scrolling data preloading

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I've implemented an infinite scrolling on a page, it works good, when the page is scrolled to bottom, the data is loaded, but I want to do some kind of preloading of data to prevent user to wait each time he reaches the bottom of the page. I really need an advice for this, cause I don't really know ho to do it (A good example that I saw, is on Pinterest, they preload data before scroll reaches the bottom of the page). Thanks guys

*A snippet from my code*

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var $scrlTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $docHght = $(document).height();
    var $wndwHght = $(window).height();

    if  ($scrlTop == $docHght - $wndwHght){                    

        loadMore();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `loadMore()` when the scroll gets to the very bottom, how about some time before that?

```
if ($scrlTop >= $docHght - $wndwHght * 2) {
   loadMore();
}
```

Comment: It's not working right, cause on first scroll to bottom all the data from database is shown.

Comment: @DenisHoss are you saying that `loadMore` loads *all* of the data rather than just "more?"

Comment: right, cause after first load the `$scrlTop` will be always bigger than `$docHght - $wndwHght * 2`